# How do I start Ubuntu's ufw before fail2ban to solve a loss of connectivity issue?

Tags: systemd, ufw, fail2ban

My skill level configuring systemd is more of a newbie and need help as I've now hit a road block and I'm stuck.

I have fail2ban and ufw installed on a Raspberry Pi clone board. The problem I've identified is that there are now over 1000 IP addresses blocked and in fail2ban's database. Also ufw also starts-up as inactive. If I issue "sudo ufw enable" too soon then all network connectivity is lost and I have to use the board's power button to shut-down and power-off the Ubuntu Linux OS on the board.

Wjhat I believe is happening is while fail2ban is populating iptables and ip6tables when ufw starts, fail2ban already has iptables running and ufw's rules get messed up.

Does anyone know how, using systemd, I can prevent the fail2ban.service from starting until ufw.service starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Before=` and `After=` to express ordering in systemd, in the `[Unit]` block.

If you're writing these unit files yourself, just put them there. If you're not, you can run `sudo systemctl edit fail2ban.service`, and then in the editor enter:

```
[Unit]
After=ufw.service
```

`systemctl edit` is a shortcut that creates a new file, `/etc/systemd/system/fail2ban.service.d/override.conf`, with the contents you enter and reloads systemd; you can also do those steps manually.

You might also want a `Requires=ufw.service`, if you want to prevent fail2ban from starting without ufw (and also have it stopped automatically if ufw is stopped)

Before and After are documented in the [`systemd.unit` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

Comment: Thank-you. This seemed to have worked. ufw initialised correctly once fail2ban starts after ufw.